# error C2228: left of '.glClear' must have class/struct/union

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

```
void triangle(void)
{
 glClearColor(0.0, 0.0. 0.0, 1.0);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, .2, .8);
 glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
 glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
 glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
 glVertex2f(0.5, 0.0);
 glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
 glEnd();
 glFlush();
}

int main()
{
....
.....
}
```

i tried to run this program.. But it is saying that:

> ```
> error C2228: left of '.glClear' must have class/struct/union
> ```

build is failed.. If I exclude the statement `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0. 0.0, 1.0)`, I am getting no errors and program also executing.. What might be the mistake? Of course my program is running if I do like that, but I wanna know the reason why it is so happening..

Answer (score 3):

```
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0. 0.0, 1.0);
                         ^
                         |
                         |
                  Should be a comma.
```